MediaWIki: Moved server and visual editor not working, error on edit button
I moved MediaWiki 1.37.1 to a new server location, the edit button gives an error now.
[36608ab44f7e307376a5e9ba] Exception caught: Could not open '/home/user_****/tmp_zswknl/mw-GlobalIdGenerator1021-UUID-128'.
I moved the files and database and changed LocalSettings to reflect the new server location. I also moved the temp file outside of the website folders and relinked it. The temp folder has the same permissions as it did on the other server.
This file '/home/user_****/tmp_zswknl/mw-GlobalIdGenerator1021-UUID-128' does not exist in this location - it doesn't exist on the old server either. What is this file? Where can I get it?  Is there something I need to rebuild?
Visual editor is in the extensions folder and this is set
wfLoadExtension( 'VisualEditor' ); is set in the settings
On the help on here it says I will need to configure the parasoid settings but I can't find anything about parasoid in the file structure and no mention of any of the folders it says the file should be located.
/etc/mediawiki/parsoid/config.yaml
Is parasoid something I need to install somewhere? Or is this out of date information for a previous version of MediaWiki.
These are the only files that were in the temple directory in the old server.
mw-GlobalIdGenerator-UID-nodeid
mw-GlobalIdGenerator-UUID-128
mw-GlobalIdGenerator1120-UID-nodeid
mw-GlobalIdGenerator1120-UUID-128
mw-GlobalIdGenerator2838-UID-nodeid
mw-GlobalIdGenerator2838-UUID-128

Removing the line in the LocalSettings which defines the temporary directory path resolved this issue.
// $wgTmpDirectory = "/home/my/path/was/here";
